# Unity problems with Ubuntu 15.04 (caused by NVIDIA)

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, 15.04

I would like to use Intel graphics card and disable NVIDIA graphics card forever since it is total crap which wasted 1 month of my life trying to make it work...

I already did that and used Intel Graphics until recent kernel update (26 I guess) when configuration has been messed up.

After getting black screen on boot I finally managed to get to login loop. After I was finally able to login again Unity is not working, there is no launcher, no window title bars, nothing, I can not even press <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> OR <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to get terminal.

I need to use <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to get to terminal.

I have tried every possible approach from reinstalling unity, desktop, you name it, but unsuccessful...

What should I do (reinstall) to get unity working again?

Comment: Did you already try to disable the Nvidia card in BIOS?

Comment: @Takkat Thanks for the idea. Tried it. There is no "switch"/option in my BIOS to disable NVIDIA card unfortunately. I am using ASUS G501JW. I sthere a way to physically remove NVIDIA? :) I really hate this crap of HW not working under Ubuntu...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install NVIDIA GPU drivers properly?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/680825/how-do-i-install-nvidia-gpu-drivers-properly)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)